# Relative translation - Aruco

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, aruco

I'm using Aruco to find the relative translation between the marker and the camera, I calibrated my camera and got its intrinsic parameters.

I then have found the relative pose using `estimatePoseSingleMarkers` function in OpenCV for python.

My camera is set at a fixed position & height, the only thing changing is the position of the object in the x and y (not in z), by that I mean the object is at a table and not being moved up or down.

I noticed, however, that when changing the position of the object, all the three values of the `tvecs` got changed, including the z one, which gets larger as the object move further from the camera.

I tried to look it up online (how OpenCV estimate the translation?) but with no luck. Could someone please point me out to the way on how the relative position/translation between two frames is done?

Sorry if this sounds naive question, I'm a newbie to this thing.

Comment: Your z-axis is along the axis that goes through the center of the camera (the direction the camera is looking at). So z should get larger when you move the object away from camera. What you observe is the normal behavior. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59754199/8371691

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry if my question sounded dumb. I'm wondering then why the "y" value is. changing while the object is always laying on the floor and not being moved up or down? in other words, how is the relative translation calculated?