# Interchange the of origin of a 3D plane

Tags: c++, 3d, linear-algebra, eigen, aruco

I am working on a fiducial marker system (like [Aruco](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html)) to obtain a 3d pose of markers (3d coordinates (x, y, z)  and the roll, pitch, yaw of the marker) with respect to the camera. The overall setup is as shown in the figure.

[Marker-Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3noi.jpg)

Right now, for some reason, I am getting the pose representation of camera with respect to the marker (Thus, considering marker as an origin). But for my purpose, I want the pose representation of the marker, with respect to the camera. I cannot make changes in the way I am getting the pose, and I must use an external transformation. Currently, I using C++ Eigen library.

From what I have read so far, I have to do a rotation around the yaw (z) axis and then translate the obtained pose by the translation vector (x,y,z). But I am not sure how to represent this in Eigen. I tried to define my pose as `Affine3f` but I am not getting correct results.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ArUco, this might answer your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59754199/8371691

However, if you are using some other marker system, the most robust way is to construct the [attitude matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group) and take inverse.

It is not clear how you represent your pose, but whether you use Euler angles or quaternion, it can be easily converted into an attitude matrix, `R`.
Then, the inverse transformation is simply taking inverse of `R`.
But given the nature of the configuration space that `R` belongs to, the inverse of `R` is also the transpose of `R`, which is computationally less expensive.
In Eigen, it's simply `R.transpose()`.

If you are using ArUco with OpenCV, you can simply use built-in [Rodrigues function](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#rodrigues).
But, if you are using ArUco, `rvec` is actually the rotation of the marker with respect to the camera frame.

Comment: Hi @Kani thanks! To answer your questions, I am not using ArUco markers. But the links you've sent look interesting. One more question regarding the maths, what if the axes are not exactly inverted as shown in my image? Do I have to find a new rotation vector representing this rotation and then multiply with the one we previously calculated?

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that your camera z axis does not follow the right hand rule. In that case, you can simply do the following: find inverse of `R`, then pre-multiply that inverse by another rotation matrix (`R1`) that represents the inverting z-axis. It should be something like: `R1=[1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, -1]`